# Adjust space between base and superscript

Tags: math-mode, spacing, xetex

I noticed that, in math mode, the top right corner of some letters, such as N or K, seems to clip into the superscript that follows the letter. I'm attaching an example:

[image]

I guess a local solution could be to write `$N^{\ 2}$` instead, but I was wondering if there exists a global solution, so that I do not have to manually insert the spacing every time.

I am aware of solutions such as [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/425124/how-can-i-prevent-insufficient-spacing-between-a-letter-with-a-bar-and-a-calligr) one or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/469716/adjust-spacing-between-preceded-superscript-and-base) one, however I believe the answer to the first one refers specifically to mathcal, while the second one concerns superscripts *preceding* the letter.

In case it could be helpful, here's the preamble to my document. I am using XeLaTeX to compile.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setallmainfonts{Old Standard}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The local solution is a little toomuch. Maybe try `N^{\mkern 1.5mu 2}` (half a thin insecable space). Perhaps it is mathspec flaw?

Comment: @Bernard that does indeed look better. If anyone knows of a global solution, of course, that would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution (is not the best):

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setallmainfonts{Old Standard}
\begin{document}
$N{\,}^2$
\end{document}
```